# Include null in oracle regex

Tags: regex, oracle

I've been trying the following but it does not return any (null) values. How can I include null values in using a regular expression with oracle an in fact return everything including null. (It is necessary to use a regex as the value is replaced with a variable in python and so the value will not always be null. Otherwise i could just leave out the expression.)

```
SELECT * from table WHERE
REGEXP_LIKE (column1,'.*|NULL$')
```

Comment: `NULL` is not a string. Regex can only match a *string* pattern.

Comment: so what would be the most elegant way to do it if I wanted to include null?

Comment: You sem to be looking for null, or any (not-null) value, which makes the check a bit pointless? Or are you saying the regex *pattern* is coming from a variable, so you won't really just have `.*`? If so your example pattern is a bit confusing. As is the working you've used.

Comment: exactly. sometimes there is a different value

Answer (score 1):

Two methods.

Explicit comparison:

```
WHERE (REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '.*') OR column1 IS NULL)
```

Or replacement:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COALESCE(column1, '<NULL>'), '.*|<NULL>')
```

The second method is more dangerous, because you could already have the replacement string in the column.

Comment: The second method can be made safe by changing the alternative in the regexp from <NULL>  to  ^<NULL>$

Comment: With that said, the first method is both easier to read and understand and more efficient (no call to COALESCE on every row, and no additional string comparison for NULL values).

Comment: @mathguy - you could still get a false match if the column value is actually `'<NULL>'`; the anchors only stop it matching if that's part of a longer value?

Comment: Err... you are correct Sir.  Another idea for saving it, just changing the alternative to ^$ (and not wrapping the column in COALESCE), doesn't work either, although based on Oracle's choice to make zero length strings be the same as NULL, it SHOULD work. It just doesn't. So, the first method it is!